# Amazon S3 Anti-Hotlinking Technique: Is it bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, hotlinking

The technique is [proposed by Amit Agarwal](http://www.labnol.org/internet/prevent-image-hotlinking-in-amazon-s3/13156/). He serves an HTML file through Amazon S3 for hotlinked image requests, providing a backlink to his own website. Would this have a negative effect on *image SEO and ranking*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aws:Referer [bucket policy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) instead.

Comment: I didn't know about Bucket Policies - thanks! This solution may however be less SEO friendly than Amit's? A bucket policy denial returns a 404 error - but Amit's workaround provides a link back to the original resource, so this is better *I think*.

Comment: This only works in S3. Most people use S3 as storage only and serve the files through CloudFront, which unfortunately does not have an equivalent.